# Win32 API command line arguments parsing

Tags: c, windows, winapi, command-line, command-line-arguments

I'm writing  Win32 console application, which can be started with optional arguments like this:

```
app.exe /argName1:"argValue" /argName2:"argValue"
```

Do I have to parse it manually (to be able to determine, which arguments are present) from argc/argv variables, or does Win32 API contain some arguments parser?

Comment: http://note.sonots.com/Comp/CompLang/cpp/getopt.html

Comment: See the documentation of [WinMain](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff381406%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), the command line parameters come as a single string and not as argv/argc (though you can get it in that format through another function).

Answer (score 17, accepted):

There is no Win32 support for **parsing** command-line arguments.

See related articles at MSDN:
[Parsing C++ Command-Line Arguments](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/17w5ykft.aspx)
[Argument Definitions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/88w63h9k%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)
[Customizing C++ Command-Line Processing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zay8tzh6%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

also look at similar questions:
[What parameter parser libraries are there for C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/253556/1168156)
[Parsing parameters to main()](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9943566/1168156)
[Option Parsers for C/C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/637371/option-parsers-for-c-c)
[What's an effective way to parse command line parameters in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3826897/1168156)
...

Answer (score 9):

The only support that Win32 provides for command line arguments are the functions `GetCommandLine` and `CommandLineToArgvW`. This is exactly the same as the `argv` parameter that you have for a console application.

You will have to do the parsing yourself. Regex would be a good option for this.

Answer (score 7):

You could mess around with various libraries and stuff...  But sometimes all you require is something simple, practical and quick:

```
int i;
char *key, *value;

for( i = 1; i <= argc; i++ ) {
    if( *argv[i] == '/' ) {
        key = argv[i] + 1;
        value = strchr(key, ':');
        if( value != NULL ) *value++ = 0;
        process_option( key, value );
    } else {
        process_value( argv[i] );
    }
}
```

You get the idea...

This is assuming a normal Win32 console app as you have implied (which has a traditional `main` function).  For Win32 apps you come in at `WinMain` instead, as another person has already commented.

Comment: When using the CRT that ships with Visual Studio, you have access to the command line arguments through the [__argc, __argv, __wargv](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/argc-argv-wargv) symbols. They are populated for applications that run in the WINDOWS subsystem as well. Alternatively use the Windows API call [CommandLineToArgvW](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb776391.aspx) to parse the return value of [GetCommandLineW](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683156.aspx).

Answer (score 3):

Just for the record, if you use [MinGW's GCC](http://mingw.org), rather than Microsoft's MSVC, you get GNU getopt, (which also includes getopt_long and getopt_long_only variants), included within the standard runtime library.

Answer (score 3):

You can parse the arguments by using `GetCommandLine, PathRemoveArgs, PathGetArgs` in a loop
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb773742(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: Brittle, at best. From the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb773742.aspx): *"This function should not be used on generic command path templates (from users or the registry), but rather it should be used only on templates that the application knows to be well formed."* It's easier and safer to use [CommandLineToArgvW](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb776391.aspx) instead.

Answer (score 3):

I have been developing and using [libparamset](https://github.com/guardtime/libparamset) that is written in plain C. It is really powerful and works well on Windows.
It provides:

- Is cross-platform.
- Wildcard support for file input on Windows!
- Powerful features. See [libparamset](https://github.com/guardtime/libparamset).

Answer (score 2):

If your needs are simple, you might want to take a look at [*Argh!*](https://github.com/adishavit/argh).
It is single header and super easy to use:

```
int main(int, char* argv[])
{
    argh::parser cmdl(argv);          // declare

    if (cmdl[{ "-v", "--verbose" }])  // use immediately
        std::cout << "Verbose, I am.\n";

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

By being unintrusive, it doesn't take over you `main()` function.

From the Readme:

> #### Philosophy
>
> Contrary to many alternatives, `argh` takes a minimalist *laissez-faire* approach, very suitable for fuss-less prototyping with the following rules:
>
> The API is:
>
> - Minimalistic but expressive:
>
>   - No getters nor binders
>   - Just the `[]` and `()` operators.
>   - Easy iteration (range-`for` too).
> - You don't pay for what you don't use;
> - Conversion to typed variables happens (via `std::istream >>`) on the user side *after* the parsing phase;
> - No exceptions thrown for failures.
> - Liberal BSD license;
> - Single header file;
> - No non-`std` dependencies.
>
> `argh` does not care about:
>
> - How many '`-`' preceded your option;
> - Which flags and options you support - that is your responsibility;
> - Syntax validation: *any* command line is a valid (*not necessarily unique*) combination of positional *parameters*, *flags* and
>     *options*;
> - Automatically producing a usage message.

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe that there is a Win32 API available. You can look for a Windows implementation of [getopt](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Getopt) or another library.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure about existence of such a win32 api function(s), but [Boost.Program_Options](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_51_0/doc/html/program_options.html) library could help you.