# Unsymmetry between main and launching process

Tags: c, winapi, program-entry-point

A C main method has the signature

```
int main(int argc, char** argv) {
}
```

It will get an array of command line parameters. But when trying to launch an application, e.g. using [CreateProcess](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682425(v=vs.85).aspx) or [ShellExecute](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762153(v=vs.85).aspx), they only accept 2 parameters, one for the application to launch and one for the parameters. **Why the parameters are not specified as array, too?** Why every application that uses other applications has to deal with escaping of command line parameters, e.g., when invoking a compare tool with 2 arbitrary file names that might contain spaces or quotes?

Comment: The example functions you name use a shell to execute. Have a look at `execv()` and friends.

Comment: May as well ask why the sun rises in the east.

Comment: *Why the parameters are not specified as array, too?* but why they must ? the command line as single string the most native option. and entry point of exe have `ULONG __stdcall ep(PEB*)` signature. `main` not a entry point

Comment: You are comparing the C standard to the Windows API. These aren't comparable. The question is a bit of a non sequitur.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On very few system the actual program execution actually start at the `main` (or `WinMain`) or similar function. Instead the compiler tells the linker to use a special function which usually doesn't really take *any* arguments, in the C sense of the word.

The command-line arguments (if *any*) could be passed through special registers on the assembly level, or they needs to be fetched using special OS-specific functions (like [`GetCommandLine`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683156(v=vs.85).aspx) in the Windows API).

On Windows, the [`GetCommandLine`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683156(v=vs.85).aspx) function does indeed get the command line as a single string. Just like it was passed to e.g. `CreateProcess`.

For a Windows console program, the special "entry" function does some other initialization (like setting up `stdin` etc.), and then calls [`GetCommandLine`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683156(v=vs.85).aspx) to get the command-line arguments, which it then parses into an array suitable for the `main` function, which is then called.

---

If you look at the POSIX world (where e.g. Linux and macOS lives) then they have [the `exec` family of functions](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/exec.3.html) which does indeed take an array for the arguments. Or a variable-argument list which is parsed into such an array.

Comment: Are there convenience methods that split a command line string into its parts or escapes the parts to get a command line string?

Comment: @ThomasS. See [Win32 API command line arguments parsing](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12689142/440558).

Comment: *"In Windows all programs really start with the WinMain function."* - That's not entirely correct. The entry point for all Windows applications is `DWORD EntryPoint()`. The compiler runtime support library performs its initialization, and dispatches to the correct user-provided entry point. Using default settings and the Microsoft Compiler, there is no `WinMain` when targeting the `CONSOLE` subsystem.

Comment: @IInspectable Reworded answer, quite considerably.

Comment: @IInspectable - yes, in general this is true, but if want be 100% exactly - the signature of exe entry point is `DWORD __stdcall EntryPoint(PEB*)` but if we use `DWORD EntryPoint()` - this also will be work without problems

Comment: *Instead the compiler tells the linker to use a special function* - no, usually compiler (say cl.exe) nothing tell the linker about entrypoint/ the `/ENTRY` this is linker, not compiler option. we direct tell the linker entry point (not via compiler) or linker select it by default based on subsystem

Comment: ...`EntryPoint` should not return, it must call `ExitProcess`.

Comment: @Anders - usual yes, but not mandatory. another thread can call `ExitProcess`.

Comment: It is pretty mandatory that a generic `EntryPoint` function calls `ExitProcess`. I don't even think the PE docs say what happens if you return.

Comment: @Anders - the any thread of process can call `ExitProcess`. absolute not mandatory that this will be the first thread (which started from entry point). what happens if entrypoint return - `ExitThread` will be called with return value. dont know about docs, what i say is by fact (current implementation in all windows versions)